# SetAdapter is not working in ListView of Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-arrayadapter

I am working an Android project where there is a tabbed view in one particular layout, there is a tabbed view. So i used layout fragments in that situation. There is a `ListView` in one of the fragments. The `listview` is basically a Timeline View, which will show data from a particular data-set. Data is being retrieved successfully, but `SetAdapter` function is not working.

Here is the main View class of the Tabbed Activity,

```js
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

import com.impresscapital.iclapp.util.AboutICLPagerAdapter;

public class AboutICLMain extends AppCompatActivity
implements AboutICL.OnFragmentInteractionListener,
WalkThroughAchievements.OnFragmentInteractionListener,
DirectorManagement.OnFragmentInteractionListener{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_about_iclmain);
        generateUI();
    }

    public void generateUI(){
        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.about_icl_page_tabs);
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("About ICL"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Achievements"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Directors and Management"));

        tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);

        final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        final AboutICLPagerAdapter adapter = new AboutICLPagerAdapter
                (getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());

        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
        tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });


    }

    @Override
    public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri) {

    }
}
```

Now to Fragment Activity

```js
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.impresscapital.iclapp.data.ICLAchievementsData;
import com.impresscapital.iclapp.database.AppDatabase;
import com.impresscapital.iclapp.database.AppExecutors;
import com.impresscapital.iclapp.dbobj.ICLAchievements;
import com.impresscapital.iclapp.util.GetICLAchievements;
import com.impresscapital.iclapp.util.TimeLineAdapter;

import org.qap.ctimelineview.TimelineRow;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.zip.Inflater;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 * Activities that contain this fragment must implement the
 * {@link WalkThroughAchievements.OnFragmentInteractionListener} interface
 * to handle interaction events.
 * Use the {@link WalkThroughAchievements#newInstance} factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 */
public class WalkThroughAchievements extends Fragment {
    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";
    private Context context;



    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;
    private ListView achievementListView;
    private AppDatabase mDb;
    private ArrayList<ICLAchievements> achievements=new ArrayList<ICLAchievements>();
    private ArrayList<TimelineRow> timelineRows=new ArrayList<TimelineRow>();

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    public WalkThroughAchievements() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment WalkThroughAchievements.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static WalkThroughAchievements newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        WalkThroughAchievements fragment = new WalkThroughAchievements();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;

    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
        context=getContext();
    }

    private void generateUI(){

        final TimeLineAdapter adapter=new TimeLineAdapter();
        ICLAchievementsData data=new ICLAchievementsData();
        achievements=data.getAllData();
        timelineRows=adapter.generateTimeLine(achievements);
        ArrayAdapter<TimelineRow> achievementAdapter=new
                ArrayAdapter<TimelineRow>(
                context.getApplicationContext()
                ,R.layout.fragment_walk_through_achievements,
                timelineRows);
        achievementListView.setAdapter(achievementAdapter);


    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater=getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
        View iclAchievementView=layoutInflater.inflate(
                R.layout.fragment_walk_through_achievements,
                container,false
        );
        achievementListView=iclAchievementView.findViewById(R.id.timeline_icl_achievements);
        generateUI();
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_walk_through_achievements, container, false);
    }

    // TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
    public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    /**
     * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
     * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
     * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
     * activity.
     * <p>
     * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
     * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
     * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
     */
    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }

    public ArrayList<ICLAchievements> getAllAchievements(){
        GetICLAchievements getICLAchievements=new GetICLAchievements();
        return getICLAchievements.getAllAchievements(context);
    }
}
```

And the fragment Layout

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".WalkThroughAchievements">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/timeline_icl_achievements"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp" />

</FrameLayout>
```

My Adapter Code is bellow:

```js
package com.impresscapital.iclapp.util;

import android.graphics.Color;

import com.impresscapital.iclapp.R;
import com.impresscapital.iclapp.dbobj.ICLAchievements;

import org.qap.ctimelineview.TimelineRow;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class TimeLineAdapter {

    private ArrayList<TimelineRow> timelineRowsList=new ArrayList<TimelineRow>();

    public  ArrayList<TimelineRow> generateTimeLine(ArrayList<ICLAchievements> achievements){
        int rowId=0;
        for(ICLAchievements achievement:achievements){
            TimelineRow achievementRow=new TimelineRow(rowId++);
            achievementRow.setTitle(achievement.getAchievementDate());
            achievementRow.setDescription(achievement.getAchievementText());

            achievementRow.setBellowLineColor(Color.argb(255, 0, 0, 0));
            achievementRow.setBellowLineSize(1);
            achievementRow.setImageSize(10);
            achievementRow.setBackgroundSize(10);

            achievementRow.setTitleColor(Color.argb(255, 0, 0, 0));
            achievementRow.setDescriptionColor(Color.argb(255, 0, 0, 0));

            timelineRowsList.add(achievementRow);
        }
        return timelineRowsList;
    }
}
```

Comment: post you `Adapter` code also.

Comment: In the `Fragment`'s `onCreateView()` method, you need to `return iclAchievementView;`, instead of `return inflater.inflate(...);`. Currently, you're inflating and setting up an instance of that layout at the start of the method, but then returning a completely different instance that you inflate in the `return` call. That instance doesn't have the setup you're doing in `generateUI()`.